Power BI real time updates in data automatically
I am using Power BI web version. I connected my database to it but it is not updating real time.
I am not able to find any way in which the Power BI can be udpated real time automatically. I searched on google that I cannot update my dashboards using the web version.
Can any one help me in how can I get my dashboard updated automatically in real time?
